# How to trigger submitting form automatically and use preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two ways of using form on a page. 
**First** one is standard way when user types something in input field and clicks the submit button. 
**Second** one is that the form is automatically filled and submitted depending on if a query string is passed to a page. (`www.website.com/contact?fillform=true`)

Everything works fine except I need yet to trigger the submit button for when query string is passed but currently it just refreshes the page.

I have done part in PHP, I have checked variables and they are ok.

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jYPJqb?editors=1010), `e.preventDefault()` is commented out since it doesn't work on window load

```
$(window).load(function() {

    // Function for submitting form 
    function submitForm(e) {

        console.log('I am in');

        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            ... // Submit form
        })

    }

    // Normal way of submitting form, works ok
    $contactForm.on('submit', function(e) {
        submitForm(e);
    });


    // This should trigger form automatically
    if(fillFormAutomatically) {
        // Everything so far works ok
        // I just need to trigger form without page refresh but none of these works
        $submitBtn.trigger('click');
        $submitBtn.triggerHandler('click');
        $contactForm.submit(e);
        $contactForm.submit(function(e) {
            console.log(e); // nothing in console shows here
            submitForm(e);
        });
        submitForm(); // This triggers function but I can't pass event?
    }

});
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML so we can fiddle.

Comment: Ok, I have prepared Codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a couple of problems.

.load() was depreciated in jQuery 1.8, so don't use that. See: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Secondly, when you call submitForm() on window.ready(), there is no event. So you're trying to call .preventDefault() on undefined. Just move it to the .submit() function.

Does that answer your question?

```js
  $(window).ready(function() {
    
    var $form = $("#form");
    var $submitBtn = $("#submitBtn");

    // Send form on window load
    submitForm();

    // Normal way
    $form.submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      submitForm(e);
    });

    // Send form
    function submitForm() {
        $('#vardump').append('Sending form...');
    }
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" value="Somedata">
  <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
  
</form>

<div id="vardump"></div>
```